# g++ finds -lXext but MinGW cannot find it with error: i586-mingw32msvc/bin/ld: cannot find -lXext

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, mingw, cross-compiling

I can build a Linux executable with g++ like below without any problem:

```
g++ -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/FL/images -I/usr/include/freetype2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_THREAD_SAFE -D_REENTRANT -o '2016_02_06a_1st_Window' '2016_02_06a_1st_Window.cxx' /usr/local/lib/libfltk.a -lXext -lXft -lfontconfig -lpthread -ldl -lm -lX11
```

But When I try to build a MS Windows executable with MinGW like below and error happens:

```
i586-mingw32msvc-g++ -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/FL/images -I/usr/include/freetype2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_THREAD_SAFE -D_REENTRANT 2016_02_06a_1st_Window.cxx -L/usr/local/lib -lfltk -lXext -lXft -lfontconfig -lpthread -ldl -lm -lX11 -o 2016_02_06a_1st_Window.exe
```

The error of MinGW is:

```
Compiling and linking..
/usr/lib/gcc/i586-mingw32msvc/4.2.1-sjlj/../../../../i586-mingw32msvc/bin/ld: cannot find -lXext
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have installed all kinds of Xext libraries like these:

---

[image]

### [image]

---

I have the following Xext libraries on my machine:

```
user@computer:~$ locate *Xext*
/usr/include/X11/extensions/Xext.h
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.a
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6.4.0
```

I feel like g++ knows where Xext libraries are, but MinGW doesn't know. Any idea would be helpful.

Comment: Is `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/` a default location for the MinGW linker to look for libraries? How did you install the Xext package in MinGW? Where did you find the files? The `.so` extension doesn't look right for Windows, shared libraries should be normal DLL's.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg That's the problem. MinGW doesn't look for libraries inside those locations, and even if MinGW does so, the libraries are in Linux format (.so) not Windows (.dll). I don't know the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are running a cross compiler, which host is linux and target is windows, so when you link your target binaries, you should have target libraries. in your case, you should have libX for windows, and you listed are linux libraries, that's why your cross compiler cannot find libraries to link.

Comment: Right, I feel like I should figure out equivalent of Xext libraries (and possibly other ones) in Windows platform.